# Literary use of dieser/jener

Tags: literature, demonstrative-pronoun

> Ein weiser Mann redet unparteiisch von Freunden und Feinden und übersieht jener ihre Fehler noch weniger, als er dieser ihre Tugenden zu rühmen vergißt.

I have tried my best to unravel the reason for dieser/jener in this sentence. I read that it could be former/latter type of construction. But the declension looks like it is doubling the position of the „weiser Mann“. I know this is 300 years old, but I have seen ‚dieser’ used in similar ways and just took it for granted; if someone could expand on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dieser" and "jener" in this example work quite similar to "this" and "that", or "these" and "those" in English.

In more contemporary German, your quote could be phrased as

> Ein weiser Mann spricht unparteisch von Freunden und Feinden und übersieht die Fehler von jenen noch weniger, als er die Tugenden von diesen zu rühmen vergisst.

This is a bit of an indirect use of the difference between "diese" und "jene". On the face of it, the difference refers to distance:

> Diese Schuhe (die nahe bei mir stehen) sind sauber, aber jene Schuhe (die weiter weg stehen) muss ich noch putzen.

In your quote the difference is, so to speak, the distance from the second clause. With reference to "[Er] übersieht jener ihre Fehler noch weniger, als er dieser ihre Tugenden zu rühmen vergißt", the "Freunde" are a bit farther away than the "Feinde".

Regarding the "jener ihre Fehler" construction, this is a mostly outdated way of expressing possession. You'll find in (very) casual speech and/or some dialects expressions like

> Das ist der Monika ihr Schuh.

instead of the contemporary German

> Das ist Monikas Schuh.

Your quote works similarly: "Jener ihre Fehler" would be something like "die Fehler jener" or "die Fehler von jenen" in contemporary German, and "dieser ihre Tugenden" would be "die Tugenden dieser" or "die Tugenden von diesen".

Answer (score 5):

It is a former/latter construction, but very unusual. "Jener ihre Fehler" refers to the faults of the friends, "dieser ihre Tugenden" are the virtues of the enemies.

Unusual is the use of "jener ihre" instead of just "jener" and "dieser ihre" instead of just "dieser". The author seems to insert "ihre" to avoid a grammatical ambiguity that would arise with "jener Fehler" und "dieser Tugenden". I'm not even sure if it was more usual to do it that way back then, but it's definitely unorthodox today in written language.

Today I would probably either work with *erstere* und *letztere*, repeat the nouns *Freunde* and *Feinde*, or at least change the word order:

> Ein weiser Mann redet unparteiisch von Freunden und Feinden und übersieht Fehler ersterer noch weniger als er Tugenden letzterer zu rühmen vergisst.

> Ein weiser Mann redet unparteiisch von Freunden und Feinden und übersieht Fehler jener (*or:* von jenen) noch weniger als er Tugenden dieser (*or:* von diesen) zu rühmen vergisst.

Comment: "unorthodox" is quite the understatement. I'm a native speaker, lived in Germany for more than 35 years, consider myself educated and I would not have been able to parse that sentence correctly. But your explanation makes sense. [DWDS: jener](https://www.dwds.de/wb/jener) does not explain it, but apparently it's a subject that warrants [scientific articles](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jbgsg-2012-0023/pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In modern German, the combination "dieser ihre"/"jener ihre" sounds very strange. But there are some dialects that use a similar form instead of genitive: "Anne ihr Kleid" instead of "Annes Kleid".

In this example, I can't find a reason to use "diese" und "jener", because both refer to the same, "Freunde und Feinde". Maybe it is for style because the author doesn't want to repeat the same word. While using the same word too often can be boring to read, using different words for the same object can make a text hard to read.

I would use the word "deren" instead of both "jener ihre" and "dieser ihre".

> Ein weiser Mann redet unparteiisch von Freunden und Feinden und übersieht **deren** Fehler noch weniger, als er **deren** Tugenden zu rühmen vergißt.

Comment: This is not equivalent, because the important information that *Fehler* belongs to *Freunde* only and *Tugenden* to *Feinde* only is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I too had to read several times to figure out the references. I have indicated them with A, B, and C:

> Ein weiser Mann (**A**) redet unparteiisch von Freunden (**B**) und Feinden (**C**)
>
> und übersieht jener (**B**) ihre Fehler noch weniger,
>
> als er (**A**) dieser (**C**) ihre Tugenden zu rühmen vergißt.

The challenge is to recognize that *jener ihre* und *dieser ihre* belong together. In contemporary German, one would certainly rephrase it. For example, I would write:

> Ein weiser Mann (**A**) redet unparteiisch von Freunden (**B**) und Feinden (**C**),
>
> und er (**A**) übersieht die Fehler jener (**B**) noch weniger,
>
> als er (**A**) die Tugenden dieser (**C**) zu rühmen vergißt.

Notice that I repeated *er* in the second main clause and that I changed the positions of *jener* and *dieser*.